# Evaluate $L(1, \chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n}$ for $\chi$ mod $3$

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-character

Here is the homework question I am working on:

> Evaluate (as a real number) the series
> $$L(1, \chi_3) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_3(n)}{n},$$
> where $\chi_3$ is the unique nontrivial Dirichlet character mod $3$.

My work is as follows:

We have that
\begin{align*}
        L(1, \chi_3) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_3(n)}{n} &= \frac{\chi_3(1)}{1} + \frac{\chi_3(2)}{2} + \frac{\chi_3(4)}{4} + \frac{\chi_3(5)}{5}  + \frac{\chi_3(7)}{7} + \cdots \\
        &= 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{11} + \cdots \\
        &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{10} + \cdots\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{11} + \cdots\right) \\
        %&= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3n + 1} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3n - 1} \\
        &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3n + 1} - \frac{1}{3n - 1}.
    \end{align*}
Now, we define
$$f(x) = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3n + 1}}{3n + 1} - \frac{x^{3n - 1}}{3n - 1}$$
and differentiate termwise to find that
\begin{align*}
        f'(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n} - x^{3n - 2} \\
        &= \frac{x^3}{1 - x^3} - \frac{x}{1 - x^3} \\
        &= \frac{x(x^2 - 1)}{1 - x^3} 
    \end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
        f(1) &= 1 + \int_0^1 \frac{x(x^2 - 1)}{1 - x^3} \\
        &= 1 + \left(\frac{\sqrt3 \pi}{9} - 1\right) \\
        &= \frac{\sqrt3 \pi}{9}
    \end{align*}

Is this the correct answer and method?

Comment: You answer is correct as illustrated by [this WolframAlpha evaluation of $L_{3,2}(1)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DirichletL%5B3%2C+2%2C+1%5D+).

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I didn't know the wolfram-alpha notation of Dirichlet L-series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer and method are indeed correct.

---

Here is another simple method which gives the same value.  First, note that

$$\chi_3(n)=-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}3(e^{i2n\pi/3}-e^{-i2n\pi/3})$$

We therefore have that

\begin{equation}
f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_3(n)}{n}x^n=-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}3\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2n\pi/3}}{n}x^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-i2n\pi/3}}{n}x^n\right]=\frac{i\sqrt{3}}3[\log(1-e^{i2\pi/3}x)-\log(1-e^{-i2\pi/3}x)]
\end{equation}

for $|x|<1$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_3(n)}{n}$ converges via the alternating series test, then by Abel's theorem,

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_3(n)}{n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=\frac{i\sqrt{3}}3[\log(1-e^{i2\pi/3})-\log(1-e^{-i2\pi/3})]=\frac{i\sqrt{3}}3\log(e^{-i2\pi/6})=\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{9}
\end{equation}
as desired.